# Getting a full resolution image after compiling a montage

Tags: css, matlab, image-processing

I'm using MATLAB to montage several high-resolution images together, register the overlay coordinates into a text file, then reading the text file and loading the montaged image. However, once I have the montage, the individual images making up the montage lose resolution. Is there a way to to display the montage with the full resolution of each individual image still intact?

Here is the code.

```
file = 'ImageFile.txt';
info = importdata(file);
ImageNames = info.textdata(:,1);
xoffset = info.data(:,1);
yoffset = info.data(:,2);
for i=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffx(i) = xoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - xoffset(i,1);
end
diffx = (diffx)';
for j=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffy(j) = yoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - yoffset(j,1);
end
diffy = (diffy)';
colormap(gray(256));
for k=1:length(ImageNames)
    imshow(ImageNames{k,1}, 'XData', [diffx(k,1) (size(ImageNames{1},2) + diffx(k,1))], 'YData',[diffy(k,1) (size(ImageNames{1}, 1) + diffy(k,1))]), hold on
end
```

Comment: you can use imread() to get pixel values of every image, store all images in  a structure. Finally simply combine all 3d matrices to achieve your montage. Save the final matrix with imwrite(). This won't loose the original resolution. But the montage created would be a very high resolution image. Hope you have a strong GPU to handle it.

Comment: What do you mean "lose" resolution? How exactly are you loading your images in?  Some code would be awesome so that we can reconstruct your problem.

Comment: hey @raryreng, the problem i'm having is that my images are 1002x1004 pixels in size and around ~2MB each, however when I use MATLAB to montage a bunch of them together and save the montage, the resolution in the final montaged image is low. 
I'm using imread to load them in and imagesc to display.

Comment: Hi @Damon , that's exactly what I need. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to do this simply?

Comment: this is the code
`code`
file = 'ImageFile.txt';
info = importdata(file);
ImageNames = info.textdata(:,1);
xoffset = info.data(:,1);
yoffset = info.data(:,2);
for i=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffx(i) = xoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - xoffset(i,1);
end
diffx = (diffx)';
for j=1:length(ImageNames)
    diffy(j) = yoffset(length(ImageNames),1) - yoffset(j,1);
end
diffy = (diffy)';

colormap(gray(256));
for k=1:length(ImageNames)
    imshow(ImageNames{k,1}, 'XData', [diffx(k,1) (size(ImageNames{1},2) + diffx(k,1))], 'YData',[diffy(k,1) (size(ImageNames{1}, 1) + diffy(k,1))]),
    hold on
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the method that I used to implement montage. You might not feel the same.**

I would assume that you have the co-ordinates of every image location in final montage.

Say I have to create a montage of 9 images and they are named as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg,... 9.jpg.

```
for i=1:9
    filename = sprintf('%d.jpg',i);
    a{i} = imread(filename);
end

montage = [a{1} a{2} a{3}; a{4} a{5} a{6}; a{7} a{8} a{9}];

imshow(montage);
imwrite(montage, 'montage.jpg');
```